# RBS and Fail Over Cluster with SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, clustering, failover, blob

I am trying to install one SQL Server 2012 cluster with two nodes. I will also be enabling Remote Blob Storage (RBS) on server so I was wondering if I need to take something in account while installing cluster?
Or I can install cluster like we normally do and then later on enable RBS like we normally do?  I mean does RBS require some special configuration/setting in SQL Fail Over Cluster?

Comment: Do you mean [Remote Blob Store](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg638709.aspx) or remote blob storage using [FILESTREAM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645886.aspx)?

Comment: I mean RBS using FILESTREAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup is pretty strait forward. As the TechNet article below states you need to make sure the Windows Share Name is the same across all nodes.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645886.aspx